# How to get the title of the selected UIActionSheet button into a label?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I have a button with some options.

```
- (IBAction)monstrarActionSheet:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *action = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Titulo"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Mejor no" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Que miedo" otherButtonTitles:@"Otro boton 1", @"Otro boton 2", nil];
    [action showInView: self.view];
```

When an option is selected I show a message in logs to show which button was selected.

```
-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    /*if(actionSheet.tag == 1){

    }*/

    NSLog(@"El usuario seleciono el boton %ld", (long)buttonIndex);
}
```

And in my `ViewController.h` my button and label are defined like that

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbViewController1;
```

How can I put the selected `UIActionSheet`'s button's title into my `lbViewController1` label?

Comment: Put what value in your label?

Comment: The text value of the option selected @LyndseyScott

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`UIActionSheet` has been deprecated so you should be using `UIAlertController` of type action sheet for iOS 8.0+, but to answer your question using your current code, you can set your label to contain the button's title like so:

```
-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    /*if(actionSheet.tag == 1){

    }*/
    NSLog(@"El usuario seleciono el boton %ld", (long)buttonIndex);
    self.lbViewController1.text =  [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
}
```

Comment: Your question's wording is a bit confusing though, so let me know if I didn't answer your question...